# Using pc internet connection for android development phone

Tags: android, adb, android-4.4-kitkat, tethering

Is it possible to share internet connection of mavericks or windows to to a phone connected for android development(usb debugging mode)?

i dont mean reverse tether of usb, i want my developing/debuggins apps on phone to use pc/macs ethernet connection for internet access

Answer (score 0):

Number of softwares are available for internet sharing.
One such software is mHotspot.
With mHotspot you can share internet while developing android apps.